# How to access the tuple values from .partition()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Today I've learned that string partition(sep) gives me a tuple with the before, separator, and after params.

Let's say I have this:

```
string = 'Plans for this weekend include turning wine into water.'
print(string.partition('weekend '))
```

and it prints out:

`('Plans for this ', 'weekend ', 'include turning wine into water.')`

How do I grab the value in the third index?

Thanks in advance! (I'm pretty new to Python :)

Comment: `string.partition('weekend ')[2]`. A tuple is a lot like a list, and you can index into it the same way (the third element has index `2`).

Answer (score 0):

Just store the result in new variable and access it through its index.

```
string = 'Plans for this weekend include turning wine into water.'
res = string.partition('weekend ')
print(res[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
string = 'Plans for this weekend include turning wine into water.'
print(string.partition('weekend ')[2][0])
```

This will print out `i`

`print(string.partition('weekend ')[2])`

Output: `include turning wine into water.`

**It works like array/list referencing.**